# Overdetermined Nonlinear Least Square fitting: How to define those $f_i$s?

Tags: optimization, least-squares

In this [article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NonlinearLeastSquaresFitting.html), at the bottom of the page, for the overdetermined case, it is said that

> An analogous technique can be used to solve an overdetermined set of
>   equations.[...] In such a case, write the $n$ different functions as
>   $f_i(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$ for $i=1, ..., n$ and call their actual
>   values $y_i$ [...]

However, I couldn't understand in which way we should define those $f_i$s ?

I mean I'm trying to do the same fitting for the same type of gaussian and I have more than $100$ data point and $3$ parameters only, so how should I define those $f_i$s so that fitted function will minimise the difference between all those data points ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the example in your link (I changed $x_0$ there to $b$ in order to avoid confusion with data points $x_i$). You are trying to find parameters $A, b, \sigma$ to best fit observed data to $$Ae^{-(x-b)^2/(2*\sigma^2)}$$  For each of your 100 data points, the ith of which well call $x_i$, there is a corresponding observation $y_i$.  In this case, $$f_i = Ae^{-(x_i-b)^2/(2*\sigma^2)}$$ The ith residual, $$r_i = y_i - Ae^{-(x-b)^2/(2*\sigma^2)}$$  Nonlinear least squares then finds the values of $A, b, \sigma$ to minimize $$\frac{1}{2}\Sigma r_i^2$$

Note: the $\frac{1}{2}$ is optional, and is for convenience to make certain things work out nicer.

In your case, all $f_i$ are of the same form.  But this framework allows for different data points to have different functional forms.  Also, instead of the ith input data value being a scalar $x_i$, it could be a vector of multiple inputs per data point.